# Combine and transpose

Tags: google-sheets

I have a table that looks like this:

| Year | Month | Customers | Country |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022 | January | 12 | Argentina |
| 2022 | January | 4 | Australia |
| 2022 | January | 6 | Brazil |
| 2021 | December | 8 | Argentina |
| 2021 | December | 4 | Australia |
| 2021 | December | 2 | Brazil |
| 2021 | November | 12 | Argentina |
| 2021 | November | 4 | Australia |
| 2021 | November | 14 | Brazil |

I want to consolidate the year and month columns, and transpose the rest of the data for a result that looks like this:

| Year | Month | Argentina | Australia | Brazil |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022 | January | 12 | 4 | 6 |
| 2021 | December | 8 | 4 | 2 |
| 2021 | November | 12 | 4 | 14 |

Is there any way to do this in Google Sheets?

Answer (score 1):

Try below `QUERY()` function.

```
=QUERY(A1:D10,"select A, B, min(C) group by A,B pivot D order by A DESC")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Use this formula**

```
=QUERY(QUERY({A1:D}, " Select * Where Col1 is not null "),
                    "Select Col1, Col2, min(Col3) group by Col1,Col2 pivot Col4 order by Col1 Desc")
```

[image]

Comment: No need query function twice. You can use where condition in same query function.

Comment: thanks for the note, I got autopilot mode and nested it.